# python regular expressions - how to get all the names in a line?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, names

How do i get the names from the line like below, using regex ??

```
line #1==> 
Elector's Name: Surpam Badurubai Elector's Name: Madavimaru Elector's Name: Madavitannubai 

line #2==>
Elector's Name: GEDAM KARNU Elector's Name: GEDAM BHEEM BAI Elector's Name: Surpam Rajeshwar Rav
```

I've tried

```
regex = "\s*Elector\'s\sName\:\s([[a-zA-z]*\s[a-zA-z]*\s*[a-zA-z]*]*)\s" 
re.findall(regex, line)
```

It was working for line 1 but is not able to fetch the last name.
For line 2, it only fetched 'Surpam Rajeshwar' from the last name but it actually has 3 words in it.

I Appreciate, if someone could help me with this or suggest me a different way to get the names. !!

Comment: Use a raw string for your RE, and you probably want the leading and trailing whitespace to be "zero or more":  `regex = r"\s* ... \s*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do that without a regex by splitting with `Elector's Name:`, stripping the resulting items from whitespace and dropping all empty items:

```
ss = ["Elector's Name: Surpam Badurubai Elector's Name: Madavimaru Elector's Name: Madavitannubai",
   "Elector's Name: GEDAM KARNU Elector's Name: GEDAM BHEEM BAI Elector's Name: Surpam Rajeshwar Rav"]
for s in ss:
    print(filter(None, [x.strip() for x in s.split("Elector's Name:")]))
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wDfyAQ), output:

```
['Surpam Badurubai', 'Madavimaru', 'Madavitannubai']
['GEDAM KARNU', 'GEDAM BHEEM BAI', 'Surpam Rajeshwar Rav']
```

Just in case you want to study regex, here is a possible regex based solution:

```
re.findall(r"Elector's Name:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*Elector's Name:|$)", s)
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/u2dOOi)

**Pattern details**

- `Elector's Name:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (this value is returned by `re.findall`): any 0+ chars other than line break chars (with `re.DOTALL`, including them) as few as possible
- `(?=\s*Elector's Name:|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ whitespaces and `Elector's Name:` after them or the end of string (`$`) immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, for helping me with a neat description. I've applied this and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Looks that it's more a job for `re.split` according on the `"Elector's Name: "` text (with optional spaces before or after), chained in a list comprehension to filter out empty fields:

```
[x for x in re.split("\s*Elector's Name:\s*",l1) if x]
```

with your examples I get those outputs:

```
['GEDAM KARNU', 'GEDAM BHEEM BAI', 'Surpam Rajeshwar Rav']
['Surpam Badurubai', 'Madavimaru', 'Madavitannubai']
```

note that you can achieve this using `str.split()` chained to `str.split()` as well:

```
[x.strip() for x in l1.split("Elector's Name:") if x]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to get all names maybe try `.split()` with delimiter `Elector's Name:`. Like :

```
names = line.split('Elector's Name:')
for i in names:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jamie Zawinski:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

So, using python

```
line = "Elector's Name: Surpam Badurubai Elector's Name: Madavimaru Elector's Name: Madavitannubai"
[name.strip() for name in line.split("Elector's Name:") if name != '']
```